# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

Ia have the following data container which is constantly being updated:

```
  data = []
        for val, track_id in zip(values,list(track_ids)):
            #below
            if val < threshold:
                #structure data as dictionary
                pre_data = {"artist": sp.track(track_id)['artists'][0]['name'], "track":sp.track(track_id)['name'], "feature": filter_name, "value": val}
                data.append(pre_data)
        #write to file
        with open('db/json/' + user + '_' + product + '_' + filter_name + '.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data,f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

but I am getting a lot of errors like this:

`json.dump(data,f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
 File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)`
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)`

Is there a way I can get rid of this encoding problem once and for all?

I was told that this would do it:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

but many people do not recommend it.

I use `python 2.7.10`

any clues?

Comment: Show the full error trace so we can see where the error is coming from. And is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: `sys.setdefaultencoding` maybe worked in Python2 but doesn't exists in Python3. And it could work with `print()` but not with other thing like write to file so you have to show full error message and line which makes problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom updated, thanks

Comment: @furas full error above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write to a file that was opened in text mode, Python encodes the string for you. The default encoding is `ascii`, which generates the error you see; there are a *lot* of characters that can't be encoded to ASCII.

The solution is to open the file in a different encoding. In Python 2 you must use the `codecs` module, in Python 3 you can add the `encoding=` parameter directly to `open`. `utf-8` is a popular choice since it can handle all of the Unicode characters, and for JSON specifically it's the standard; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_portability_issues.

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('db/json/' + user + '_' + product + '_' + filter_name + '.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Comment: You beat me to it! The [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-8.1) only allows utf-8, utf-16 and utf-32 encodings but puts restrictions on the second two (no BOM for instance) and hints that utf-8 is the only interoperable way to do it. `mbcs` would violate the rfc. I thought JSON was utf-8 only and was surprised that the other encodings are even allowed.

Comment: @tdelaney I've never dealt with JSON directly so I was unaware of the character set restriction, thanks! I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your object has unicode strings and python 2.x's support for unicode can be a bit spotty. First, lets make a short example that demonstrates the problem:

```
>>> obj = {"artist":u"Björk"}
>>> import json
>>> with open('deleteme', 'w') as f:
...     json.dump(obj, f, ensure_ascii=False)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

From the `json.dump` help text:

```
If ``ensure_ascii`` is true (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the
output are escaped with ``\uXXXX`` sequences, and the result is a ``str``
instance consisting of ASCII characters only.  If ``ensure_ascii`` is
``False``, some chunks written to ``fp`` may be ``unicode`` instances.
This usually happens because the input contains unicode strings or the
``encoding`` parameter is used. Unless ``fp.write()`` explicitly
understands ``unicode`` (as in ``codecs.getwriter``) this is likely to
cause an error.
```

Ah! There is the solution. Either use the default `ensure_ascii=True` and get ascii escaped unicode characters or use the `codecs` module to open the file with the encoding you want. This works:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> with codecs.open('deleteme', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
...     json.dump(obj, f, ensure_ascii=False)
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not encode the specific string instead? try, the `.encode('utf-8')` method on the string that is raising the exception.